# Problems with ${(z)var}

Tags: variables, zsh

Code:

```
HOST=localhost
PORT=1234
RSYNCCMD="rsync -avP -e \"ssh -p $PORT\""

${(z)RSYNCCMD} root@$HOST:"\"/foo\"" /bar
```

Output:

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh -p 1234: No such file or directory (2)
...
```

If I enter the same thing (`rsync -avP -e "ssh -p 1234" ...`) directly into the console, it works.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Try to define function Echo: `function Echo() { for a in $@ ; do echo -E - $a ; done }` and replace `rsync` with `Echo`. What does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `${(Q)${(z)RSYNCCMD}}` might work for you (instead of `${(z)RSYNCCMD}`)

(`${(z)RSYNCCMD}` seems to be expanded to `rsync -avP -e \"ssh\ -p\ 1234\"`, (Q) does an additional unquoting magic)

Comment: What are your options? That does not happen in my case.

Comment: Understood. Yes, your answer should work, but topic starter may also consider using `eval ${(z)RSYNCCMD} ...`.

Comment: `eval` has other problems, basically that I have to quote all of the rest. But the solution with `(Q)` works fine, thanks.